# How to test Flutter app where there is an async call in initState()?

Tags: asynchronous, testing, dart, flutter

I have a StatefulWidget that does an async call in its `initState()`, to build a Widget. When I manually run this, the widget does build quickly.

However, in my test, even if I use `await tester.pump()` or `await tester.pumpAndSettle()`, the widget doesn't seem to get built, until way after the test has run.

Widget code:

```
Widget _coolWidget;

@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  _coolWidget = Container(); // If I set this to OverflowBox() my test passes
  _buildWidgetFromCanvas();
}

Future<void> _buildWidgetFromCanvas() {
  final ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  final ui.Canvas canvas = ui.Canvas(recorder);
  // ... more canvas drawing code ...
  final img = ... // Image.memory() I build from the canvas
  if (!mounted) {
    print('no longer mounted');
    return;
  }

  setState(() {
    print(img);
    _coolWidget = OverflowBox(
      child: img,
    );
    print(_coolWidget);
  });
}
```

Test code:

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('''OverflowBox shows up.''', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    await _setUp(tester); // Just instantiates my widget in an app
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    expect(find.byType(OverflowBox).evaluate().length, 1);
  });
}
```

An output when I run my test results in:

```
failed: Error caught by Flutter test framework, thrown running a test.
Expected: <1>
Actual: <0>
```

But if I set `_coolWidget = OverflowBox();` in `initState()`, the test passes.

I have other tests that run after this one. After those ones are done, I see the print logging the `print(img);` and `print(_coolWidget);` from above, and it correctly logs the drawn image.

I also get the `no longer mounted` print, but that only happens as the very last print, prior to Flutter's built in `(tearDownAll)`.

Setting durations in the pump() and pumpAndSettle() don't seem to change anything.

I'm probably missing something obvious.

Comment: Possibly related? https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/23179 Even though I'm not adding assets, I guess creating a png and then loading it from memory is kind of like an asset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `FutureBuilder` if your `build` method relies on async work.

```dart
Future<Image> _buildWidgetFromCanvas() {
  final ui.PictureRecorder recorder = ui.PictureRecorder();
  final ui.Canvas canvas = ui.Canvas(recorder);
  // ... more canvas drawing code ...
  if (!mounted) {
    return null
  }
  final img = ... // Image.memory() I build from the canvas
  return img;
}

FutureBuilder<Image>(
  future: _buildWidgetFromCanvas, // a previously-obtained Future<Image> or null
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.none:
      case ConnectionState.active:
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return SizedBox(height: <height>, width: <width>);
      case ConnectionState.done:
        return OverflowBox(child: snapshot.data);
    }
    return null; // unreachable
  },
)
```

You can also update your test code like this:

```dart
  expect(find.byType(OverflowBox), findsOneWidget);
```

Comment: I've put the `FutureBuilder<Image>(...)` code into my initState(), since I want the widget to be built as early as possible. Visually it behaves as expected, though when I run a test it still doesn't seem to find my widget.

Comment: I don't think you want the `FutureBuilder` in your initstate.  You could try to make your `buildWidgetFromCanvas` cache its last value and call it from initState.

Comment: Now, in initState() I have set a var, `_savedFuture = _buildWidgetFromCanvas()`.  I've moved my `FutureBuilder` into build(), and my `future` property is now `_savedFuture`. It seems that the `ConnectionState.done` case is never reached when running the test (I have a print in that case, which is not printed).

Comment: In a separate class (another project) I was able to use FutureBuilder and test it properly!

Answer (score 0):

I have a future builder that is stuck on waiting, and it's not finishing or throwing any errors. The futurebuilder has a future which loads a file so it should be able to do it. The app works fine but the test does not.

````
    // Create the widget by telling the tester to build it.
    await tester.pumpWidget(
        MaterialApp(home: DisplayPictureScreen(key: _globalKey, imagePath: 'test.png', onUpload: upload))
    );
    // Create the Finders.
    final safeAreaFinder = find.byKey(_globalKey);
    // expect we have one positioned widget
    expect(safeAreaFinder, findsOneWidget);
    await tester.pump();
    expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
    // test code here
    await tester.pump(const Duration(seconds: 20));
    expect(find.byType(Expanded), findsOneWidget);
  });
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The [pumpAndSettle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/WidgetTester/pumpAndSettle.html) method accepts a Duration argument so you can mimic the passage of time. The test doesn't actually wait for the duration to pass (eg. I can add Duration(seconds: 60) and it will finish as soon as all scheduled tasks are complete).

```
void main() {
  testWidgets('CounterViewModel smoke test', (WidgetTester tester) async {
    // Setup - Arrange
    await tester.pumpWidget(MaterialApp(builder: (context, child) => const DataView()));
    final DataViewModel model = tester.state(find.byType(DataViewModelBuilder));

    expect(model.name, null);

    await tester.pumpAndSettle(const Duration(seconds: 3));

    expect(model.name, 'Falco');
  });
}
```